# Regex commas to spaces

Tags: php, regex

i need a regex that converts commas to spaces. I know this is super simple, but i do not know regex. thanks.

```
tag1, tag2,  tag3, tag4,tag5 tag6
```

to

```
tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5 tag6
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find: ",\s*"` (without quotes)

replace with: `" "` (without quotes, just a single space)

or:

```
s/,\s*/ /g
```

Answer (score 1):

Yuku's got it right. Here's in context:

```
preg_replace('/,\s*/', ' ', 'tag1, tag2,  tag3, tag4,tag5 tag6');
```

If some of your tags without commas between them have more than one space, you could use this instead:

```
preg_replace('/,\s*|\s+/', ' ', 'tag1, tag2,  tag3, tag4,tag5 tag6');
```

Comment: your second regex there returns this: `" t a g 1 t a g 2 t a g 3 t a g 4 t a g 5 t a g 6 "` since `,?\s*` matches an empty string (0 or 1 comma, 0 or more spaces)